# mpv play all the videos in just one window

Tags: video, mpv-media-player

I am utilizing kubuntu's default video player - mpv.

I want all the video will only played in one window, for instance.

```
video01.mkv
video02.mkv
video03.mkv
```

When mpv is playing video01.mkv, if I click video02.mkv, then the current mpv window will play it immediately rather than open freshly another window, so as the case of video03.mkv

However, my mpv player will play the 3 videos in three distinct windows.

How could configure it to play all the videos in just one window?

Comment: `mpv` isn't Kubuntu's default video player. Please check and confirm what the video player is.

Comment: It's mpv, if not default, I installed it and foget.

Comment: You can do that by having the videos in a playlist. Then, pressing `>` moves you to the next video (using the same window) and `<` takes you to the previous video.

Answer (score 1):

A) the simple solution: just "drag 'n' drop" a video file from your file manager. That replaces the running video immediately, inheriting its settings (volume setting, speed, brightness, ...)

B) not so simple:
write a wrapper script to load your video in your
running instance of `mpv`, else start an instance

Prerequisites:

- `wmctrl` and `socat` must be installed (both should be found in all
  the Ubuntus' repositories)
- this line is needed in `mpv`'s config file:

  `input-ipc-server=/tmp/mpvsocket`

(you should find that file in `/home/your/.mpv` or `/home/your/.config/mpv`)

---

Create a script, say `mps.sh`, in your `/home/your/bin` directory, to hold the following code:

```bsh
#/bin/bash
fle=$1
if ! pgrep -x "mpv" >/dev/null ; then
mpv "$fle"
else
wmctrl -x -R gl.mpv
echo "{ \"command\": [\"loadfile\", \"$fle\"] }" | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
fi
```

Make it executable, then make it default for some video formats via <kbd>right-click</kbd> on a video file, then → *Open With* → *Open With Other Application*.

---

**How it works:**

- if not pgrep finds 1 mpv-instance, play file
- else wmctrl find window with class name gl.mpv, ##1
- bring to foreground in current workspace
- load file to that window using socat ##2

**Things to check if it doesn't:**

##1 maybe the window class is different on your system?
Start any video in mpv, then execute this in a terminal:

```bsh
wmctrl -xl | grep mpv
```

The line showing your videos title in the last column shows the class name in the third column.
Replace my `gl.mpv` with that.

##2 check the `socat` functionality with this command in a terminal, while a video is playing:

```bsh
echo '{ "command": ["set_property", "pause", true] }' | socat - /tmp/mpvsocket
```

If this does pause the video, the socat connection works. Time to triple check the quotes and backslashes in its script line. These are needed in exactly the way given above, because we have the variable `$fle` there. There's no variable in the "pause" example.

If the  "pause" example doesn't work, I can't help better than: check evrything again, reboot machine, and have your fingers crossed ;-))

Comment: Thanks for editing, BeastOfCaerbannog. The whole thing still being a mess, I'll have another go at it. Please, do feel invited to edit the next version, too

Comment: @ BeastOfCaerbannog: I'm sorry, I must have deleted everything of the former versions, the whole editing history, when rewriting it from scratch. I didn't mean to, but it happened. Again: feel free to improve it ...